# My shoes have dyed a different colour after cleaning

Tags: cleaning, shoes

I have a pair of shoes (Nike squash type) that needed a clean. I used Daz powder and a baking soda mixture to clean away the grass and mud stains. They came up fine but after drying I noticed that the entire toe sections on both shoes had turned orange and black. I don’t know how to remove it or if I can at all! I only recently bought these so I’d really appreciate any help on how to bring them back to life!

[image]
(click to enlarge)

Answer (score 1):

**My shoes have dyed a different colour after cleaning?**

There are only one possible solutions that I can think of and I am not entirely sure that they would work.

- Soak the entire area of the shoes with [**Shout**](https://www.shoutitout.com/en-us)! I have had great success, with this product in the past, but this is a new domain more myself. I would recommend being generous with this product and let it soak in somewhat longer than the recommended time before washing it in cold water.

If this fails I would simply wear them as is for outdoor hiking or yard work.

Comment: Why not color them black if all else fails?

Comment: @OlaStröm You can, but in my experience colour do not come out evenly.